# Inspecting a HTML form shows that buttons are not part of it

Tags: html

Following is the HTML content inside `<body>` tag

```
<div class="container mt-5 pt-2 pb-4" id="container-primary">
<div class="container mt-3" id="container-secondary"><h3>Welcome</h3><br> Please Enter your <strong>Password</strong> to view the question</br>
</div>
<div class="container pt-2" id="container-tertiary">
  <form method="post" id="pwd-form" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="password" class="form-control mx-auto" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" spellcheck="false"></input>
    <div class="container" id="pwd-error-container"><?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['wrongpwd'])){
      echo $_SESSION['wrongpwd'];
      unset($_SESSION['wrongpwd']);
    } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="container mx-auto" id="button-container">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-left" id="forgotpwd" value="Forgot Password">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" id="submit-button" value="Validate" disabled>
    </div>
 </form>
```

There are two buttons inside the `<form>`. But when I `inspect` the webpage in the browser, I observed that those two buttons are not inside the `<form>`. What actually is causing the problem?

Following is the css:

````
  #container-primary{
    background-color: ;
  }
  #container-secondary{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #container-tertiary{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  #pwd-form{
    background-color: green;
  }
  #pwd{
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

  }
  #pwd-error-container{
    background-color: ;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: rgb(217, 48, 37);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #button-container{
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  #question-form{
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  #answer{
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  </style>```


I don't know where I have gone wrong. Screenshots of the inspection have been given in the comments section.
````

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @janitha [URL] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAbRZWOEnrnn6nZTYdjAua7P3yI9eLCP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Kumar Add background color to form and check it what happen.

Comment: @janitha https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kiVeYQJnW4-aHC1bljDTvkC73OsL_aAO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @janitha I added the background-color and it got added only to the password input field.

Comment: without the css looks ok, so it must be the css you applied

Comment: @Kumar Remove the container class from button-container and check it

Comment: @Erica T. You are right. I think also.

Comment: @EricaT  I updated the question with css. Please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: @janitha   I updated the question with css. Please tell me where I have gone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your *float-left* and *float-right* classes from button.Then it work fine.

```
<div class="container" id="button-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mr-auto">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="forgotpwd">Forgot Password</button>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submit-button" disabled>Validate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lebxp70k/44/

Answer (score 1):

your html code is invalid.  You have closing tags where none are required and you are missing other closing tags that are required.  Here's a corrected version

```css
#container-primary{
    background-color: ;
  }
  #container-secondary{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #container-tertiary{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  #pwd-form{
    background-color: green;
  }
  #pwd{
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

  }
  #pwd-error-container{
    background-color: ;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: rgb(217, 48, 37);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #button-container{
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  #question-form{
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  #answer{
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5 pt-2 pb-4" id="container-primary">
  <div class="container mt-3" id="container-secondary">
     <h3>Welcome</h3><br> 
         Please Enter your <strong>Password</strong> to view the question<br>
  </div>
  <div class="container pt-2" id="container-tertiary">

     <form method="post" id="pwd-form" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" class="form-control mx-auto" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" spellcheck="false">
        <div class="container" id="pwd-error-container"><?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['wrongpwd'])){
      echo $_SESSION['wrongpwd'];
      unset($_SESSION['wrongpwd']);
    } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="container mx-auto" id="button-container">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-left" id="forgotpwd" value="Forgot Password">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" id="submit-button" value="Validate" disabled>
    </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you probably added the last two closing div's. But that doesn't matter a lost when we go for inspection. But your code looks absolutely fine as I can see from the snippet but mine was not fine. The only difference is the head part. When I removed all jQuery, Bootstrap links from my code it worked fine. So, may be jQuery or Bootstrap is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

here's your html.  You can clearly see in the snippet that the form tag is in red i.e. it's not closed.  The problem is both your < /br > and your < /input > tags.  < /br > should just be < br > and < input > tags do not get closed with < / input >

```html
<div class="container mt-5 pt-2 pb-4" id="container-primary">
<div class="container mt-3" id="container-secondary"><h3>Welcome</h3><br> Please Enter your <strong>Password</strong> to view the question</br>
</div>
<div class="container pt-2" id="container-tertiary">
  <form method="post" id="pwd-form" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="password" class="form-control mx-auto" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" spellcheck="false"></input>
    <div class="container" id="pwd-error-container"><?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['wrongpwd'])){
      echo $_SESSION['wrongpwd'];
      unset($_SESSION['wrongpwd']);
    } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="container mx-auto" id="button-container">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-left" id="forgotpwd" value="Forgot Password">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" id="submit-button" value="Validate" disabled>
    </div>
 </form>
```